# Syntax for using 'not'?

Tags: entries

I want to show a list of entries that excludes two or more specifically by id.

This works:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('boardOfDirectors').id('not 12') %}
```

This does not:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('boardOfDirectors').id('not 12,18') %}
```

Is this possible?
Anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to start with `and`, and put `not` in front of each ID...

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('boardOfDirectors').id('and, not 12, not 18') %}
```

Comment: I've tried this (and some other variants) and its just not working...

Comment: Looks like I skipped a step... Try putting `and` at the beginning. See [this other SE post](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12781/45) for more information.